# Access a non-default IIS site outside of a server

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

There are 2 sites in my IIS 7.5 server. In the server (Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard), the default site is http://localhost:80 and the non-default site is http://localhost:27100. Let's say that the external URL is http://example.com, which currently points to the site with port 80, how to I access to the one with the port 27100 externally?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://hostname.com:27100. In your case, if you have DNS A-record to translate http://example.com to this server, then you can use http://example.com:27100